# Sort numeric values except text in Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I have a csv file called prices.csv that looks like this:

```
Name, Price, Description
Apple, 2.85, fruit
Kiwi, 1.96, fruit
Banana, 0.99, fruit
Peach, Not available, fruit
Orange, 2.02, fruit
```

I would like to sort the second column (Price) in ascending order, except for the values that are 'Not available', these should be placed at the bottom.

What I've done so far is this:

`sort -t, -k2,2 -n prices.csv > ordered_prices.csv`

This creates the following file:

```
Name, Price, Description
Peach, Not available, fruit
Banana, 0.99, fruit
Kiwi, 1.96, fruit
Orange, 2.02, fruit
Apple, 2.85, fruit
```

As you can see this places the products with price 'Not available' at the top instead of at the bottom. How do I place the text at the bottom with generic code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `gnu-awk` then you can do this using `PROCINFO`:

```
awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {
   print
   next
}
$2+0 == $2 {
   a[NR] = $2
   rec[NR] = $0
   next
}
{
   rest = rest $0 RS
}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
   for (i in a)
      print rec[i]
   printf "%s", rest
}' file
```

```
Name, Price, Description
Banana, 0.99, fruit
Kiwi, 1.96, fruit
Orange, 2.02, fruit
Apple, 2.85, fruit
Peach, Not available, fruit
```

Alternatively you can use `head + tail + sort` command like this:

```
head -n 1 file && sort -t, -k2V <(tail -n +2 file)
```

Comment: Hi, your first solution using awk works. I don't know why you deleted it but it was the correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: No I didn't delete Awk solution. Just formatted it to make it more redable.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using version sort instead of a numeric sort:

```
$ sort -t, -k2,2V  prices.csv > ordered_prices.csv
```

More information about version sorting can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort). Note that this will move your header to the back. You could use this method:

```
$ OUTPUTFILE=outputfile
$ awk -v out="$OUTPUTFILE" '(NR==1){print > out; close(out)}(NR>1)' inputfile \
  | sort -t, -k2,2V > $OUTPUTFILE
```

But that is super ugly and at this point I would switch to the solution of Anubhava.

Another way you could do this is by doing a ridiculous substitution:

```
$ sed '2,$s/\([[:alpha:]]\+\)/999999\1/g' | sort -t, -k2n | sed 's/999999//g'
```

which keeps the header in place.

Comment: @anubhava you are correct. I added an ugly fix for it.